# Why does strpos function in first condition always return true?

Tags: php, conditional-statements

Something is wrong with my code.  No matter what the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` value is, `gkPageContent` is always displayed.

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "online") >= 0) {
    $left_col_class = "gkPageContent";
}
elseif(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "student-login") >= 0)  {
    $left_col_class = "showme";
    echo "this is not sanjay";
}
elseif(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "my-account/orders") >= 0)  {
    $left_col_class = "showme";
}
elseif(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "my-account/my-courses") >= 0)  {
    $left_col_class = "showme";
}
elseif(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "my-account/fourm") >= 0)  {
    $left_col_class = "showme";
}
elseif(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "student-login") >= 0)  {
    $left_col_class = "showme";
}
elseif (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "student-login") >= 0)  {
    $left_col_class = "showme";
}
else{
    echo "dam thing";
}

echo $left_col_class;
```

Here's a [demonstration](https://3v4l.org/rlAKm).

Why isn't  `strpos()` evaluating the string as intended?

Comment: Well it's not utilising the Joomla API for starters. Are you getting any errors with the code? If not try setting error reporting in the Joomla Global Configuration to **development**

Comment: Adding an explanation of what you are trying to do and what's not working might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strpos returns false if a value is not found.  False is treated the same as 0.  That means `>= 0` will always be true.

Change that to `!= false` and it should work.

That said, Lodder's comment is correct - you should be using Joomla's api and framework for a Joomla site, assuming you are posting in the correct forum (and if not, you might want to look at `switch` instead of lots of messy elseifs).

Getting the [itemid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067435/joomla-get-menu-item-id) will probably do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your battery of conditionals, I'm sorry to say, is bloated, redundant, and inefficient.  Whenever I see a long-winded if-elseif-else or case-switch block, I recommend a lookup array.  A lookup array will be far more compact, easier to read/maintain, and requires far less function calls.

Here's how you generate the lookup:

1. Isolate the `needle` value that you'll be searching for and use these unique values as keys.
2. Isolate the value(s) that you will want to access upon finding a match.

For simplicity, I'm going to omit the mention of `"this is not sanjay"` because it will add complexity to the lookup array structure and over-complicate my demonstration.

```
$lookup = array(
              'online' => 'gkPageContent',
              'student-login' => 'showme',
              'my-account/orders' => 'showme',
              'my-account/my-courses' => 'showme',
              'my-account/fourm' => 'showme'       // check your spelling
          );
```

See, this is clean and compact and if you accidentally duplicate a key-value pair then only one will be retained because php array keys must be unique.

Now to use the lookup, you only need to call upon the speedy `isset()` function one time like this:

```
if (isset($lookup[$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']])) {
    $left_col_class = $lookup[$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']];
} else {
    $left_col_class = $default_fallback_value; // ..."darn thing" would be unhelpful, me thinks
}
```

Finally, if you need to access multiple values from a key match, then instead of assigning strings like `gkPageContent` and `showme`, you can assign an array to each key like: `array('class' => 'gkPageContent', 'note' => 'Sanjay')` or `array('class' => 'showme', 'note' => 'Not Sanjay')` and access them respectively like: `$lookup[$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']]['class']` and `$lookup[$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']]['note']`.